# Agrupar por condicion Python-Pandas (groupby)

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un dataframe con estas columnas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesito agruparlo donde solo se cuenten los "TRUE" de ambas columnas quedando algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si uso groupby() me realiza el conteo tanto de los true como los false, y no se como colocar una condicion para solo contar lo que necesito

Comment: No cuentes, simplemente haz una suma, los TRUE sumarán 1 y los FALSE = 0. Si agregas un ejemplo  y el código que tienes hasta ahora será mas sencillo darte  una respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como sugiere [Patricio Moracho](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/31764/patricio-moracho)... podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd

diccionario = { 'Codigo': ['Cod_1']*7 + ['Cod_2']*8,
                'CA': [True]*4 +[False,True,False]+ [True]*3 +[False]+ [True]*4,
                'SD': [True,False,True]+[False]*2+[True]*6+[False]*2+[True,False]
}

# Creamos un dataFrame con los datos de «diccionario»
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=diccionario, orient='columns')

print(f"┌─┤ df ├─┐\n{df}\n")

'''
┌─┤ df ├─┐
   Codigo     CA     SD
0   Cod_1   True   True
1   Cod_1   True  False
2   Cod_1   True   True
3   Cod_1   True  False
4   Cod_1  False  False
5   Cod_1   True   True
6   Cod_1  False   True
7   Cod_2   True   True
8   Cod_2   True   True
9   Cod_2   True   True
10  Cod_2  False   True
11  Cod_2   True  False
12  Cod_2   True  False
13  Cod_2   True   True
14  Cod_2   True  False
'''


### Se pueden cambiar los datos de las columnas de varias formas...
#   Una opción puede ser:
#df['CA'] = df['CA'].replace({True: 1, False: 0})
#df['SD'] = df['SD'].replace({True: 1, False: 0})
#
#   Tambien se pueden cambiar los datos al multiplicar por uno (1)
#df=df*1
#
### o directamente hacer la agrupación
df_true = df.groupby('Codigo').sum()

# Renombramos las columnas
df_true.columns=['CA_True', 'SD_True']

print(f"┌─┤ df_true ├─┐\n{df_true}\n")

'''
┌─┤ df_true ├─┐
        CA_True  SD_True
Codigo                  
Cod_1         5        4
Cod_2         7        5
'''
```